# Server doesn't receive UDP packets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, heroku

I am deploying my application on Heroku, and I have a rake task that creates a UDP server:

```
udp_port = 41234
Socket.udp_server_loop(udp_port) { |data, source|
      #some logic
}
```

After starting that rake task on Heroku, I used this separate code to send a trivial UDP packet to that server:

```
require 'socket'
s = UDPSocket.new
s.send("hello", 0, server_ip, 41234)
```

But nothing happens: The UDP server running on Heroku doesn't receive any packet. However when I run the UDP server rake task on my local machine and I send the packet like this:

```
require 'socket'
s = UDPSocket.new
s.send("hello", 0, '127.0.0.1', 41234)
```

It works.

Why does my UDP server rake task receive the packet when running on my local machine, but not when running on Heroku?

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can’t access Heroku dynos directly like this. You can only access them via HTTP through the router.

Comment: I'm afraid that on Heroku you can not acces any port you want, only HTTP 80 and HTTPS 443 are allowed.